# Как преобразовать строку в массив?

Tags: python, строки

1. B000099990
2. B200099991
3. B000099990
4. B400099989

Есть такого типа вводные данные, надо чтобы можно было вызывать их по одному, как в списке.
Т.е `print(abc[n])` где `abc` это массив из этих строк
Пока что при таком способе выдает n'ую букву из первого элемента

```
print(abc[2]) = 0 
print(abc[0]) = B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = 'B400099989 B000099990 B200099991 B400099992 B600099993'
lst = s.split()
```

Для вывода всех элементов используйте цикл

```
for i in lst:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я не совсем так написал вопрос, изначальные данные идут вертикально, класс у них list

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ, все заработало)

Comment: По умолчанию `split` работает по любым пробельным символам, включая переводы строки, которые у вас там видимо и есть между строками.

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял вопрос, то строка по факту и есть массив символов, вы без проблем в цикле можете пробежаться по каждому из них:

```
abs = 'B400099989 B000099990 B200099991 B400099992 B600099993'
for symbol in abs:
    print(symbol)
```

Можно еще записать так, принцип один и тот же:

```
abs = 'B400099989 B000099990 B200099991 B400099992 B600099993'
for id in range(len(abs)):
    print(abs[id])
```